# Как отследить время загрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как написать такую функцию,которая отследила время загрузки страницы и если загрузка идет,например больше 10 секунд, скрывать прелоадер и показывать страницу такой какая она загрузилась на этот момент.

```js
  
 jQuery(window).load(function(){
 
    setTimeout(function () {
      var preloader = jQuery('.preloader_wrap');
      var anim_preload = jQuery('.preloader');
      anim_preload.fadeOut(500);
      preloader.delay(500).fadeOut('slow');
    },2500);
 
 });
```

```css
.preloader_wrap{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px; 
   background-color: pink;
}

.preloader{
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    width: 222px;
    height: 222px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: red;
    animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
    z-index: 1;
}





@keyframes spin {
  from{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }to{
       transform: rotate(-360deg);
     }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <div class="preloader_wrap">
      <div class="preloader"></div>
  </div>



<h1>Content</h1>
```

Comment: Надо считать от момента, когда дом начался загружаться или с момента когда спиннер запустился?

Comment: Когда прелоадер запустился и дум начал загружатся

Answer (score 2):

Вашу задачу, как мне кажется, стоит решать исключительно средствами css, т.к. до полной загрузки страницы сложно гарантировать загрузку скриптов и их корректную работу, а вот css и разметку для прелоадера, можно поместить сразу после открывающегося body и они будут загружены первыми. Например:

```css
.preloader{
  position:absolute;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background:lightgrey;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  animation: hidePreloader;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes hidePreloader {
    from {left:0vw;}
    to {left:-100vw;}
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader">
</div>
```

Я прячу прелоадер через 3 секунды (`animation-delay: 3s;`), чтобы не так долго было ждать. Можете прятать его через 10.